# Overriding Joomla 3.0 components. Possible to override model and controller too? Not just views?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-component

I understand the ability to overide core views in Joomla using overides, but how about the models and controllers? I would like the ability to add a field to the core user registration form, but Joomla pulls all the fields from an xml located in the models folder.  I could just create a plugin, but that creates its own section, and I need it to go exclusively in the main registration form, as I am creating a tiered registration.

My question is exactly how the title implies, can you create component overrides of model and controller files in joomla, rather than just views?

Further, I know I "could", but in the event of an update I want to make sure this is an acceptable override solution - not just a hack that will be subject to be overwritten.

Thanks!!

Comment: First, the plugin fields being in their own section of the page is just a convenience since the default layout just loops through the unknown fields. Since you know the fields there is no reason that you have to do that looping, you should use a specific layout naming the individual fields you want.  But yes you can override naything in Joomla, there is some documentation about this in the wiki but in your case I think it is unnecessary to go that way.  A form plugin can  modify that form also. http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can, i used MVC Override 1.0.11, is Joomla 3.x compatible.

in my case i used to override /models from component com_tag

structure in your template in this form:
/code/YOUR_COMPONENT/models/tag.php

above is my example

and you can do override correctly. the link is:
http://gruz.org.ua/en/extensions/joomla-mvc-override/1_0_11.html

Comment: This plugin raised errors. Fatal error: Call to a member function setup() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\libraries\gjfields\variablefield.php on line 222